# Как переместить файлы?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, xubuntu, linux

Здравствуйте!

Требуется с компьютера на Windows 8 скопировать некоторые документы на ноутбук с Xubuntu 13.10. Оба компьютеры подключены к одному wifi роутеру.
Как скопировать файлы по вайфаю?
Как сделать тоже самое для Windows 8 -> Windows 7?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вообще влом возиться - то можно Teamviewer на обоих компах поставить - там и удалённое управление, и копирование файлов, и даже тоннель можно прокинуть!

Comment: Можно чуть поподробней?

Comment: В TeamViewer, после успешного подключения, в окне сеанса сверху есть панель управления Тимвьюером (её ещё можно задвинуть, а при необходимости выдвинуть обратно). В ней есть вкладка "Передача файлов". Попробуйте, довольно удобно! Помимо прелести удалённого управления. А тоннель - это обычная VPN, реализованная средствами Тимвьюера. Для этого надо установить драйвер (это есть в самом Тимвьюере, в дополнительных настройках). Более полную инфу можно найти здесь: http://www.teamviewer.com/ru/

Comment: @Anton  Reshin, я вот не понимаю людей - с ТимВьювером возиться не лень, а с флешкой - лень. Чудны крестьянские дети...

Answer (score 2):

начнем по-порядку.
**задача 1.** Получить на машину с lin файлы с машины win:
1.1. Lin-машина инициатор соединения. На машине с lin должен быть установлен samba-клиент. При использовании Gnome, запускаем Nautilus, нажимаем Ctrl+L появляется адресная строка, для подключения к win-машине пишем smb://ip-вашей-win-машины/
1.2. обратный вариант. На lin машине следует настроить samba-сервер. Пересаживаемся за win-машину и... Т.к. это на порядок сложнее для Вас, чем в вар. 1.1 - то нет смысла описывать.
Все.
**задача 2.** как скопировать файлы по вай-фай:
2.1. так же как и по проводной сети - различий никаких.
**задача 3.** win7 to win8 (или наоборот - без разницы):
3.1. проверить что обе винды находятся в одной рабочей группе (workstation), для сети установлен признак "домашняя" или "рабочая" на обоих машинах и ip-адреса из одной подсети. Если все сделано - ищем машины в сетевом окружении.

*Извините, но судя по качеству заданных вопросов, Ваш идеальный вариант - это флешка или DVD-RW.*

Comment: @Justicet, с флешкой лень возиться. То о чём вы написали я и сам нагуглил. Я думал есть совсем простые способы - просто расширить папки друг для друга и всё...

Comment: просто расшарить папки это у WinXP, и то, опять если тачки в одной подсети и группе.  Флешка - САМЫЙ простой вариант, без минимального гемора

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте dropbox или яндекс.диск и не мучайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

- на линукс самбу и создать общую   папку. после этого с винды можно   копировать в общую папку.
- на    линукс ssh сервер, а на   винду -    программу win-scp. После   этого можно    будет скопировать файл   на линукс по    секьюрному   подключению

Comment: Ваши ОБА варианта сложнее, чем samba-клиент на Linux`е (напоминаю - Линукс машина инициатор соединения и она сама забирает с ЛЮБОЙ win-машины файлы. Нет даже необходимости расшаривать папки. Прверено на собственном опыте)